# How To Make a Nullable Integer Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, integer, nullable

I'm just start to make an application. I got some textfield that must filled with integer value, but when the textfield is empty, I want the value is still null in database rather than must add "0".

it's something like this

```
        DR.IN = Me.txtIn.Text
        DR.OUT = Me.txtOut.Text
```

the two of that is integer value, that when i'm save to data base the error comes and said

> The Nullable Object Must Have Value

I must add "0", but I want the data is still null. Do anyone know how to do that?

thanks for your help and sorry for really bad grammar, I hope someone out there would understand my question :)

Comment: What is `DR.IN` and `DR.OUT`? Where is the error raised?

Comment: Me.txtIn.Text != nothing then Me.txtIn.Text else nothing.But make sure `DR.IN` and `DR.OUT` are nullable ints.Something like Dim DR.IN? as int

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's class that I made

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh uumm.. I'm not sure I understand that, sorry

Comment: @Matt has come up with what I meant.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh oh, I'm really sorry, because I'm new in vb.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a conditional check using the If Operator to return either Nothing (null) if there is no text in the textbox or the integer value of the textbox:

```
Dim value As Integer? = If(TextBox1.Text.Length = 0, Nothing, Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: hey, yeah! this is all I need. Thank's so much!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown some rather important information but I'm going to assume that you are using the `Value` property of your `Integer?` without first checking whether it actually has a value.  That's the whole point of a `Nullable`: it can have a value or not.  You can't use the value if there isn't one.  Saving an `Integer?` might look like this:

```
Dim command as new SqlCommand

command.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET Number = @Number WHERE ID = @ID"

command.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(myNullableInteger.HasValue,
                                                            myNullableInteger.Value,
                                                            CObj(DBNull.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a nullable integer in `C#` like :

```
int? myint;
```

and in VB.net like:

```
Dim myint As Integer?
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `default(Nullable<type>)` will return you a `Nullable<type>` set to null.

Comment: My bad... Question was flagged C# initially. I'm no VB.Net expert :$

Comment: that's okay, also my bad to add C# tag, that I don't even remember I've add that tag xD